# Consecutive Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a new column called sum which calculates the sum of productioncountwotearoff until a null values occurs and then it restarts the sum again.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22SQa.png)

I'm also trying to create a new table with linekey, machinekey, starttime, endtime, date and the corresponding sum. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You need to explain your order by logic. Is it by IND column? Or a combo of DATE and IND?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. Appreciated. Fill do that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two window function sums will take care of it: first, do a running count of the nulls to create a grouping partition, and then use it to sum the numbers.

```
Select IND, LineKey, Machinery, StartTime, EndTime, Date, ProductionCountWOTearoff,
  Sum(ProductionCountWOTearoff) Over (Partition By grouping
      Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Unbounded Following) as Total
From (
    Select mytable.*, sum(Case When ProductionCountWOTearoff is null Then 1 Else 0 End)
         Over (Order By IND Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as grouping
    From mytable
)
Order By IND
```

Comment: Mine is exactly the same as @The Impaler answer.  Mine's a bit more verbose by including the window range (Rows Between) which I do with SUM() because the behavior varies across different DBMSs.

Comment: Hi Chris, Your code is working, I made a few changes there. Like ordering it by linekey, machinekey, IND. The thing is I just was the sum on the last row before the null. Not on all the rows.

Comment: Encase the Sum() in the second line inside a `Case When grouping<>lead(grouping) Over (Order By IND) Then ... End`  That will only place the sum on the last row of each group.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this: (include all the columns in terms of what level you would want the data at

```
WITH c1 AS (
  SELECT 
    IND, 
    Linekey, 
    productioncountWOtearoff,
    SUM(CASE WHEN productioncountWOtearoff IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Linekey ORDER BY IND) AS group_id
  FROM table
)

SELECT 
  IND, 
  Linekey, 
  productioncountWOtearoff,
  CASE WHEN productioncountWOtearoff IS NOT NULL THEN SUM(productioncountWOtearoff) OVER (PARTITION BY Linekey, group_id ORDER BY IND) END AS Sum
FROM c1
ORDER BY IND;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of window functions to get that result. For example:

```
select x.*,
  case when row_number() over(partition by g order ind desc) = 1 
        and pcwoto is not null
       then sum(pcwoto) over(partition by g order by ind)
  end as sm
from (
  select t.*, sum(case when pcwoto is null then 1 else 0 end) as g
  from t
) x
```